# Data (csv) into basket for arules, removing duplicates?

Tags: r, arules

I'm a beginner when it comes to R. But, I want to learn more. I'm trying to do a market bench analysis.

This is my raw data and I want to convert this to a transactions basket format:

[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Image 2]

I have tried :

```
trans <- as(split(a[,"Game.played"],a[,"sessionid"]),"transactions")
```

But, instead of the name of the game, the number of the game is only displayed. Could anyone tell me why this is happening? Also, I have cross verifies the actual data, and the association of the sessionid with the game is wrong!

I have also tried something like

```
q=read.transactions("a.csv", format = "basket", sep=",", rm.duplicates=TRUE).
```

But, this is not working out either.

Comment: Please take some time and incorporate all the relevant data in this post, but not as an image. Preferably as a small, [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) along with the desired result and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

> data into basket for arules, removing duplicates?

Here's an example on how you could remove the duplicates:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  cat=rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2:4), 
  val=sample(letters[1:5], 9, T),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
df
#   cat val
# 1   A   b
# 2   A   b
# 3   B   c
# 4   B   e
# 5   B   b
# 6   C   e
# 7   C   e
# 8   C   d
# 9   C   d
(lst <- lapply(split(df$val, df$cat), unique))
# $A
# [1] "b"
# 
# $B
# [1] "c" "e" "b"
# 
# $C
# [1] "e" "d"
library(arules)
as(lst, "transactions")
# transactions in sparse format with
#  3 transactions (rows) and
#  4 items (columns)
```